# Как найти записи в одной таблице, которым нет соответствия в другой

Tags: mysql

Есть две **большие** таблицы в **MySQL**. Теоретически между ними связь *один-ко-многим*. Практически — связь на уровне базы данных не задана, поэтому нет каскадного изменения/удаления данных во второй таблице при работе с первой таблицей. Итого: после удаления записей из первой таблицы во второй таблице остались мусорные данные.

Как найти подобные мусорные записи, если в обеих таблицах по несколько миллионов записей?

Вариант для небольших данных, в данном случае — не очень:

```
    SELECT bar.id
      FROM bar
 LEFT JOIN foo ON foo.id = bar.foo_id
     WHERE foo.id IS NULL;
```

Не обязательно ограничиваться только силами MySQL.

Comment: bash, rb, etc на ночь не подходит?

Comment: вопрос не в инструменте, а в логике подхода. ок, допустим, bash - что именно с ним делать?

Comment: я плохо представляю в каком виде мускул хранит данные в файле, но предпологаю что это текст в каком то формате, разбитый построчно и имеющий некий разделитель, я бы скриптом сначала зачитал бы в оперативку только уникальные ID'шники которые необходимо оставить из первой таблицы, а затем в цикле по каждой строке во втророй таблице я бы определял есть ли в оперативке сейчас это ID, если нет то удаляем целиком строчку.